# Pandas: How to Populate Column in df A, only where first four columns in df A match df B, from value in df B

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, key

Let's say I have a Dataframe in Pandas, 'A'

```
A = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C','D','Code'])
```

I have another Dataframe 'B'

```
B = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G'])
```

I need to add and populate the 'Code' column in 'B', only where the first four columns of BOTH dataframes match.

So, say, Dataframe 'C' would look like

```
C = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','Code'])
```

I've tried using inner merge but doesn't seem to work. Or maybe I did it wrong? Below is the code I used

```
key_column = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
C = pd.merge(A, B, on='key_column', how='left', suffixes=('',''))
```

Is the above supposed to work? Not sure how else I would go about this with Pandas.

EDIT: The above code may not be hundred percent accurate as I'm dictating it from memory, but would this work or is there another way to solve my problem?

Comment: `on=` in your code has a string instead of a variable , also there is no `join` kwarg in `pd.merge` instead you should use `how=` , how about `pd.merge(A, B, on=key_column, how='left')`

Comment: @anky the code above may not be hundred percent accurate but I was wondering if this solution would work or is this the wrong approach to getting that done. I wasn't getting any results so was wondering if there's any other solutions.